# Is there a way to check the date format in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A little background - I have to check if the report has the correct date format in a column. I need it to be dd/mm/yyyy for one report and mm/dd/yyyy on the other. Is there a way to check it without using vba? I need it to work for all possible file users, that may have different excel and windows settings.

Comment: You can apply different format to different report for same date.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [CELL function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us):

```
=CELL("format", A1)
```

This will return different format codes for the date formats, e.g.:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 15/02/2021 | D1 |
| 02/15/2021 | D4 |